# Row not found in database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rows

I am searching a row whose data is same as in my `textbox1` but it shows the error as below.

[Error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4myez.png)
[Database Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc2YQ.png)

Code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports WindowsApplication1.BBSRSDataSet1

Public Class CirricularDetails

    Private Sub CirricularDetails_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Public Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        '   Dim i As Integer
        Dim a As String = "IEEE"
        Dim x As Integer = 3
        Try
            databaseconnection()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowscount FROM Curriculardb"
            sqlinsertcommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            Try
                Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(sqlinsertcommand.ExecuteScalar())
                '  BBSRSDataSet1.Tables(0).rows(count).cells(index2) = "TRUE" Then
                MsgBox(count.ToString())
                ' For i = 0 To count - 1 Step 1 Field(Of CurriculardbDataTable)("IEEE")
                Dim BBSRSDataSet1 = New BBSRSDataSet1
                For i = 0 To count - 1
                    If BBSRSDataSet1.Tables("Curriculardb").Rows(1).ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
                        MsgBox("Record found")
                    End If
                Next

            Catch ex As SqlException
            End Try
        Catch ex As SqlException
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Indexes start at 0 not at 1

Comment: I tried it but as rows(0) in my program it shows the following error...  "There is no row at position 0."

Comment: Well you have declared and built the DataSet just two lines before. Why do you expect it to contain anything?

Comment: You are showing that `Curriculardb` exists in the database. That does not necessarily mean it also exists in `BBSRSDataSet1`, whatever that is. In any case it's probably not a great idea to perform a search by loading the entire table into a dataset and looping for a match. That's why there is the `where` clause.

Comment: so how can i add a datatable to dataset?

Comment: The SqlDataAdapter class can do this for you. But why? If you arejust interested to know if the row exists or not, you have already your answer in the count variable. Can you explain why are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually i wanted to access the "TRUE" Value below IEEE column in dbsnippet above but was not able to find a proper solution for it so after accesssing a row I also wanted to access a column after it for which i tried rows(0).field(...) but used to get this error

Comment: Can you provide me a solution as to how can i access the value below IEEE column?

Comment: Then you don't need a SELECT COUNT(*), but a SELECT IEEE with an appropriate WHERE clause and let the database do the search for you. After that you return the content of the Row with an ExecuteReader

Comment: Please make sure while performing string match you are ignoring the case.. "True" and "TRUE" are different for string comparison.